# Can microsoft chart control run with .net framework 3.5 without service pack1?

Tags: asp.net, microsoft-chart-controls

Can we use the DLL that getting from installation of microsoft chart control for f/w 3.5 service pack1 into the special application where there is not setup service pack1 for .Net 3.5?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that they [require SP1 to be installed](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=130f7986-bf49-4fe5-9ca8-910ae6ea442c&DisplayLang=en#Requirements):

> System Requirements
>
> - Supported Operating Systems: Windows Server 2003 Service Pack 2; Windows Server 2008; Windows Vista; Windows XP Service Pack 3
> - .NET Framework: .NET Framework 3.5 SP1